# replaceWith doesn't replace?

Tags: jquery

I am creating a rating widget and the idea is when a user clicks to rate, he rates and the rating stars are replaced with the number of votes. Here is my HTML

```
<div class="row rate_category">
  <div class="large-10 small-12 columns category">
    <p>Quality</p>
  </div>
  <div class="large-12 small-12 rating columns">
    <ul class='star-rating'>
      <li><a href='#' class='one-star'>1</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='two-stars rated'>2</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='three-stars'>3</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='four-stars'>4</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='five-stars'>5</a></li>
    </ul>
    <span class="votes">50 Votes</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are four rating categories *(Quality,Content,Uniqueness,Overall)* and the html for them is the same as the one above. So I am using `replaceWith` method like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li a.one-star").click(function(event){
    $( this ).replaceWith( $( "span.votes" ) );
  });
});
```

1.The `replaceWith` method doesn't replace. It just puts the number of votes on top of the rating stars.

2.Since there are 3 more html code blocks like the one above(quality,content,uniqueness and overall) and they are all the same, how do i tell javascript to make a difference(when a user clicks on the rating stars next to quality so he can rate(he rates), he gets the number of votes for quality and so on for the other categories).

Comment: It replaces when I try it: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/yJLJg/

Comment: replaceWith replaces the actual element with content provided in selector..Please define your problem clearly

Comment: I set id's on every category and added classes to each of the spans and now it works

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("ul.star-rating li a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var el = $(this),
        ul = el.closest("ul");

    el.hide();            
    ul.children().not(":first").hide();
    ul.children().filter(":first").append(ul.siblings("span.votes"));
  });

});
```