# How to make hidden span element show?

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I'm developing a webpage using zurb foundation framework.

Here is my html

```
<div class="row rate_category">
<div class="large-10 small-12 columns category">
<p>Quality</p></div>
<div id="quality" class="large-12 small-12 rating columns">
              <ul class='star-rating'>
               <li><a href='#' class='one-star'>1</a></li>
               <li><a href='#' class='two-stars rated'>2</a></li>
               <li><a href='#' class='three-stars'>3</a></li>
               <li><a href='#' class='four-stars'>4</a></li>
               <li><a href='#' class='five-stars'>5</a></li>
              </ul>
              <span class="votes qual show-for-small">50 Votes</span>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Here is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#quality").click(function(event){
  $( this ).replaceWith( $( "span.qual" ) );
});
});
```

The issue is that the span won't show because of the show-for-small class. I want the span to be kept hidden, upon rating it replaces the rating stars with the number of votes. Thanks in advance, i'm a complete newb.

Comment: possible duplicate of [replaceWith doesn't replace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137907/replacewith-doesnt-replace)

Comment: @RGraham Looks similar, but there are some differences. Now he's clicking on the DIV instead of A,

Comment: I'm clicking on the div and i added a class which created a new issue.